# Printing fields from another applet

Tags: java, applet

Applet 1 `a("www.domain.com/Applet.jar");`

Applet 1  is the one that gets the applet.jar from website
Applet 2  starts ur server;

Now from applet 2 how to print the fields of a class from applet 1

I know its something like this:

```
for (Field f : getClass().getFields()) {
   System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an `Applet Context` (get it by calling `getAppletContext()` in your Applet) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923518/1432545) SO answer).

There, you can call `getApplets()` to get an Enumeration of all Applets.